# Assistance with NGINX and Regex Rustexp Parsing with Vector VRL in YAML .yml Format

Tags: regex, vector, yaml, datadog, vector-vrl

I am attempting to parse an unfiltered & unformatted generic NGINX access log using [Vector VRL](https://vector.dev). I need am looking for a couple of examples and a push in the right direction, my first attempt using [VRL syntax](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/transforms/remap/) syntax but I have experience with basic regex and Sumo Logic (other logging systems).

Here is an example when I mean generic basic NGINX access log: (sourced from [Digital Ocean's blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-access-logs-error-logs))

> 47.29.201.179 - - [28/Feb/2019:13:17:10 +0000] "GET /?p=1 HTTP/2.0" 200 5316 "https://domain1.com/?p=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36" "2.75"

My goal is to parse and transform the log into the following below JSON presentation format, or at least in JSON so I can then use JQ to interpret the log with the below. But you can see an idea of the fields I am looking to parse with the message key names:

```
{
"file": "X",
"host": "X",
"message": "<MESSAGE> \"GET .."",
"nginx": {
"agent": "X",
"client": "X",
"method": "GET",
"path": "/",
"protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
"request": "GET / HTTP/1.1",
"server": "X", <---- Attempting to add this field here by extracting client IP from the log
"size": X,
"status": 200,
"timestamp": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"
},
"source_type": "file",
"timestamp": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.<unixtimestamp>Z"
}
```

- Please also note I am additionally trying to nest `nginx` as nested JSON within the formatted log.

VRL has a ton of [functions available](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/functions/#parse_regex) but I am not sure on my best choice going forward, should I use the Regex [parse_regex](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/functions/#parse_regex) as well as [parse_nginx_log](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/functions/#parse_regex), in which order and any other transforms? I saw you can also use [Multiple parsing strategies](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/functions/#parse_regex) but unsure how to achieve this, especially in `yml`.

I started testing with an example transform configuration below (I am strictly attempting to achieve this in `YAML .yml`), but not having much look thus far:

```
transforms:
  parse-nginx:
    inputs:
      - nginx
    type: remap
    source: | 
      .nginx = parse_nginx_log!(.message,"combined")
      .nginx = parse_regex!(.message, r'^(?P<server>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
    #.nginx = parse_json!(.message) # sets `.` to an array of objects
    #.nginx = parse_syslog(.message) ??
    #.nginx = parse_common_log(.message) ??
```

Additionally, to test the configuration would you suggest this is the best approach?

`sudo vector --config-yaml <path>/nginx-vector-config.yml`

Any help much appreciated...
TYIA!

Comment: Thanks, it was because vector is built on [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/).. removing tag